# Excel Interop failed to write (HRESULT: 0x800A03EC)

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I got an exception 0x800A03EC when I was trying to execute this command in Excel Interop

```
ws.get_Range("A2").Value= "=?9ABC"
```

It seems that interop doesn't like string that starts with "=?". I tried to solve the issue by setting Calculation mode to Manual, but unfortunately it wasn't the solution. Could anyone please tell me what I should do?

Thanks,
Kam

Comment: The formula is invalid. Do you just want to store it as text?

Answer (score 4):

Excel will interpret values starting with `=` as formulas. Therefore, store it as `'=?9ABC`, as the `'` tells Excel to interpret the string a text and not as formula.